# How to initialize an Array object?

Tags: java

I'm having trouble initializing an Array and don't really understand how to do it.

```
public class Array {
    int[] array;

    public Array(int[] array) {
        this.array = array;
    }

    public int sum() {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < this.array.length; i++) {
            sum = sum + array[i];
        }
        return sum;
    }

    public double average() {
        double av = this.sum() / this.array.length;
        return av;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Array a = new Array[3];
    }
}
```

I keep getting an error that says required: Array found: array[]

I want to make a scanner and have user input on the array but I don't even know how to initialize it in the first place

Comment: Just because you name your class "Array" doesn't make it indexable.

Comment: pass a int[] array like Array a = new Array(new int[3])

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to change

```
Array a = new Array[3];
```

To

```
Array a = new Array(new int[3]);
```

Constructor of `Array` is taking `int[]` as input arguments.

Comment: If I don't know how big the array is can i just make it new int[] ?

Comment: If you don't know the size of the `array` you can use `ArrayList` instead of `array`

Comment: @Panthy No you can't. Either follow Ruchira's suggestion or declare your array bigger than you need.